# Documentation changes for minor differences

Tags: discussion, documentation

Recently I started reviewing and editing on the Stack Overflow Documentation and noticed that quite a few proposed changes do not consider the specified version of a topic.

As an example [this change](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/146882?filter-tags=node.js) in the Node.js section. You see that his change would alter the declaration from `var` to `const`. The latter is only supported by the latest version of Node.js, so I do not think it would be wise to write it like this. Especially because it's irrelevant, the code works, in either case, the same.

Apparently, not everyone notices things like this, and as you can see in the original article from the change request, someone already put some `const` declarations in for two variables and got approved. In the current state the article doesn't look consistent and well written.

This switching between happens all over the place, and many sections have either or multiple styles in them. And this is only between ECMAScript 5 and 6, behold of what happens with ES7.

What should we do? I could go over all the articles and change the things back all the time, but I don't think that is a good solution.  Reducing the versions is neither because most of the time it's just an artificial limitation.

I think an option could be to at least add a new reason for "Doesn't consider the specified Version."

Comment: At the very least, the person who hit "Approve" should be review-banned for a while...